ChatForm and ChatField components cause a crash on android devices
I am using Expo to create a React Native project. I am using stripe for payments. I am using the CardForm component from @stripe/stripe-react-native to capture the card details to add payment methods.
This component works fine on Expo Go and ios devices however on androi devices(apk), it causes a crash. It only displays a white screen and I have to close and reopen the app.
Current output
Output on Expo Go
This is the code:
import { CardForm, useStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-react-native";
<CardForm style={styles.cardForm} autofocus />
I have tried adding plugins to my app.json, creating new android directories after adding the plug ins etc, nothing is working.

You'll need to access the device logs to find the actual error being thrown at runtime.
With that information, you should write in to Stripe Support with the exact error you find in the logs, and ideally a minimal reproduction that can be used to confirm and investigate the issue,
